# put a load image in a button$ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

My purpose is to show an "load image in a button" when I call $ajax function.This is the code:

```
            $.ajax({
                url: link,
                type: "POST",
                data : formData,
                success: function(data) {


                  $('#result').hide();


                },
                  failure: function(result){


                  }
```

When I click on the button I wanna show a load image like this:

http://img.ffffound.com/static-data/assets/6/77443320c6509d6b500e288695ee953502ecbd6d_m.gif

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `beforeSend`

```
 $.ajax({
         url: link,
         type: "POST",
         data : formData,
         beforeSend: function() {  
            // call your loading gif here     
         },
         success: function(data) {
             $('#result').hide();
            },
        failure: function(result){


              }
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use a plugin such as jQuery **BlockUI** to do this. Just call `$.blockUI()` before calling $.ajax. Then at the end of the success event, call `$.unblockUI()`.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xaLgeqer/4/).

It has the logic you want. You can fill with html your loading `div` and style it with CSS. As for the gif, better to use an image with transparent background or even better a font icon (like font awesome) which gives you spinning icons too.

Hope it helps